# Check if json contains a value in postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

From my database I have formed a json data as below. I am trying to search for a value in the json data `filedata`

```
filedata = {"{\"fc_primary_key\": \"A1234567892017/06/27\"}","{\"fc_primary_key\": \"A1234567892017/06/27\"}","{\"fc_primary_key\": \"A1234567892017/08/07\"}","{\"fc_primary_key\": \"A1234567892017/08/07\"}","{\"fc_primary_key\": \"A1234567892017/08/07\"}","{\"fc_primary_key\": \"A1234567892017/08/07\"}","{\"fc_primary_key\": \"A1234567892017/08/07\"}","{\"fc_primary_key\": \"A1234567892024/03/01\"}","{\"fc_primary_key\": \"A12345678945353\"}","{\"fc_primary_key\": \"A1234567892023/11/22\"}","{\"fc_primary_key\": \"A12345678945252\"}","{\"fc_primary_key\": \"A1234567892017-07-01\"}"}
```

In the above data I am trying to find if there is `A1234567892023/11/22` in it.

I have tried the below query

```
IF filedata::text @> JSONB '[{"fc_primary_key": "A1234567892023/11/22"}]'
THEN    
 RAISE NOTICE 'PRIMARY KEY %', 'exists';
END IF;
```

I am getting the error as below.

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: text = jsonb
LINE 1: SELECT filedata::text = JSONB '[{"fc_primary_key": "A1234567...
                              ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Please help.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name 10.11 is my postgres version

Comment: Your first code block is not SQL.  It doesn't seem to be pl/pgsql either.  What language is that?

Comment: You are casting filedata to text (what did it start out as?) and then trying to do JSONB operations on it.  If you want to use it as JSONB, cast it to JSONB.  `filedata::text::jsonb`